# Objective C error messages

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to debug an objective C program. It used to run, and I'm not sure what changes could have broken it, but it no longer runs at all. In the debugger, I now get:

```
.
.
.
unable to read unknown load command 0x80000022
unable to read unknown load command 0x80000022
unable to read unknown load command 0x80000022
Program loaded.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
run
Error calling thread_get_state for GP registers for thread 0x16131lx506^error,msg="error on line 207 of \"/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-908/src/gdb/macosx/i386-macosx-nat-exec.c\" in function \"fetch_inferior_registers\": (os/kern) invalid argument (0x4)\n"
```

I've seen several places that claim te explain the 1st warning, but none of them seem appropriate. Nothing online claims to explain the error.

Any clues as to what these errors mean in conjunction?

ETA: I just upgraded to 10.6, so it may have started then, although I'm compiling to target 10.4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this relevant?  From the [Xcode release notes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/):

> Note: GCC 4.2 cannot be used with the
>   Mac OS X 10.4u SDK. If you want to
>   build targets using the 10.4u SDK on
>   Xcode 3.2, you must set the Compiler
>   Version to GCC 4.0

Comment: I don't see a way to choose the GCC version, and all of the compiler options are listed as "GCC 4.0 - Code Generation" for example, so I don't THINK that's the issue... (Also, I'm using xcode 3.1 beta. maybe I should fix that...)

Comment: ETA: Yes, I upgraded to xcode 3.2, using gcc 4.0 and a target of 10.4, and a i386 and it seems to work. thanks!